# ASP.NET cookie does not expire

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I'm trying cookies for the first time in ASP. The problem is, the cookie doesn't expire no matter how many ways I write the code.

Making a cookie:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("test");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Checking if it exists:

```
if (Request.Cookies["test"] != null)
    Response.Write("test");
else
    Response.Write("no test");
```

It always shows "test".

Comment: Are you doing it at the same request ?  you shjould wait for the request to complete.

Comment: @Anders Abel: Yes, all the mentioned code is on master page. So I guess if I refresh a page after I first started it, it should print "no test"? Because it always prints "test", no matter how many times I refresh or hard refresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you doing this in the same request? In that case the old cookie is still present in the request, but will not be in subsequent requests.

Comment: You tell the browser to remove the cookie and it will do it in the next request to hit your site. The current request still contained the cookie - the `Request` object is unchanged when you add the request to the browser to not include the cookie in the next request.

Answer (score 0):

You have destry all cookies in client side..
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookie.expired?view=net-6.0
use this code it works for me.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i];
            var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
            var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
            document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Remarks:**
Expired cookies, if received, should be destroyed by the client application.